# How to interpolate colour or a triangulated surface

Tags: python, matlab, interpolation, triangulation, mayavi

I am near my wits end with this problem. Please bear with me as I try to explain my problem. I have a 3D model with a triangulated surface. I then need to add some data (in the form of colour) to the surface of the 3D model.  It should resemble something shown in this figure:  http://user.cscs.ch/fileadmin/user_upload/customers/users_entry_point/pictures/Visualization/Gallery/Cardiac_Therapy.png.

My problem is that I don't really know how to interpolate data over a triangulated surface. I was wondering if someone might have an idea or possible point me in the right direction.
I should mention that I am using python and mayavi but I am also willing to work with MATLAB.

Comment: Let your hardware do the work. OpenGL will do this for you if you specify colors at vertices: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655868/opengl-color-interpolation-across-vertices

Comment: Hi, so my problem isn't the interpolation from vertex to vertex. The issue is that I don't have a value for each vertex, and so I need a way to get values for the vertices where I don't have a value.

Comment: Where do you have values? Some of the vertices?

Comment: Yes I know the values at some of the vertices

Answer (score 0):

[Matlab's `trisurf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/trisurf.html) may work for you. You give it (x,y,z) coordinates and a color for each vertex.

Comment: Hi, so my problem isn't the interpolation from vertex to vertex. The issue is that I don't have a value for each vertex, and so I need a way to get values for the vertices where I don't have a value.